# css icon height issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, formatting, icons, html

I want to have a standard method of formatting "Show More" links in my HTML pages.

In HTML I use:

```
<span class="showMore">Show more details</span>
```

Then in the css, I have:

```css
.showMore {
    color: #0E4B82;
    padding-left: 18px;
    background: url("images/icons/add.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;
}

.showMore:hover {
    color: #F5891D;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

where [add.png](http://www.peopleperhour.com/images/icons/add.png) is a 16x16 famfamfam silk icon. I use JavaScript to expand some content section using an `onclick` event.

This works nicely in Firefox 3.0.5 but in IE 7 the last few pixels of the icon are chopped off. I'm looking for a workaround. Using height doesn't work on inline elements like `<span/>`. Adding a transparent border fixes the issue in IE7:

```css
.showMore {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    color: #0E4B82;
    padding-left: 18px;
    background: url("images/icons/add.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
```

But IE6 doesn't handle the transparency. Making the text bigger fixes the problem but I don't want big text. `line-height` doesn't work. Anyone know anything that may help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved the problem. I've no idea why but using `no-repeat center left` instead of `no-repeat top left` ensures IE doesn't chop off the bottom 2px of the icon. Why using `center` instead of `top` should result in the image being higher is strange but that's IE for you??

```css
.showMore {
    color: #0E4B82;
    padding-left: 18px;
    background: url("images/icons/add.png") no-repeat center left;
}

.showMore:hover {
    color: #F5891D;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: It's probably to do with how IE renders the text baseline. Good fix though, duly noted.

Comment: probably has something to do with the default line-height

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
display: block;
height: 16px;
```

Help fix the height of the span?

Comment: Yes, that fixes it in the same way as using a div instead of a span would. But then the text wraps to a newline. In this case I specifically needed an inline element and the height property doesn't apply to inline non-replaced elements, i.e. spans.